# using present tenses to express future in relative clauses

Tags: tense, relative-clauses, present-tense, future-tense, subordinate-clauses

The following three sentences, which forms are correct?

The people who will arrive at the meeting want to get some free drinks.(I can't delete will right?)

The people who arrive the meeting tomorrow need to sign their names on the paper.(no "will", right?)

The train which is refilled tomorrow morning leaves at 9 pm.(no will, because leaves means future right?)

Comment: You certainly can (and imho *should*) delete the ***will*** in your first example (or move it to before ***want*** if you want to emphasize the "future" aspect). The second example requires ***at*** before ***the meeting*** to be grammatical, but it's a stylistic choice whether to include ***will*** before ***need***, but it's not idiomatic to do this before ***arrive*** there. The third example should be  ***which will be*** - again it's a stylistic choice whether to use explicit future ***will leave***, but I wouldn't keep repeating complex tense usages where they're not necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! For the first sentence, I mean they have given a request saying they want to drink something tomorrow. "want" means now "they want to drink something tomorrow" so I should keep "will" right? It is different from the sentence“ when I grow up， I want to be a dancer" right?

Comment: oic - you're specifically saying that those people are *now* saying what they want. But I'm afraid English just isn't as precise as you might be hoping. Perhaps those people have just phoned you from the hotel they're staying in *tonight*, and they're asking you to agree to pay for their free drinks in their *current* hotel bar. But by mixing a future tense in your restrictive relative clause *who will arrive at the meeting* along with an ambiguously present/future verb ***want***, I think you're stretching the limits of clear English a bit far. It's just too temporally complex.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks so much for your kind help! But If the context is clear like when I was saying what they want now and then I passed the document to my boss. Is the first one grammatical? We need to put "will" right?

Comment: No, you *don't* need to put "will". You can call them *The people who arrive tomorrow* if you like. Or *The people arriving tomorrow*. Or forget about the verb ***arrive***, which is only creating problems because of the confusion of tenses (***do*** they need to sign *now*, or ***will** they need to sign tomorrow, after they arrive?)* and call them ***Tomorrow's** group / party / delegation* or something.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, the will is *optional*.
In the second sentence is fine as it is.
The third sentence is better written as:

> The train which **will be** refilled tomorrow morning **will leave** at 9 pm.

"leaves" is not commonly used and may not even be proper. See: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/leave.html

You said "The train which is refilled tomorrow...". "is refilled" is confusing, as "is" is present tense and "refilled" is past tense. In addition, "tomorow" is in the future. I think you meant that the train will be refilled tomorrow. A wordier way of saying this is:

> The train which **is going to be** refilled tomorrow morning **will leave** at 9 pm.

but I don't recommend that, as it is unnecessary wordy.

Following the link's pluperfect future tense:

> The train which **is going to be** refilled tomorrow morning **will have left** at 9 pm.

but this is not necessary.