# Can I use the auxiliary "will" twice in a sentence that starts with "when"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

Can I use the word "will" in two clauses of the same sentence that starts with "when"?
I've already checked all questions in this forum about the use of "will" twice in a sentence, but none of them specifically mentioned this case. Here's an example:

> When the angel of death **will** come, none **will** be able to evade
> him.

The person who says this is clearly making a prediction about the coming of the angel. However, I'm not sure whether the sentence should be:

> When the angel of death **comes**, none **will** be able to evade him.

Are both sentences correct? If so, do they have the same meaning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using present tenses to express future in relative clauses.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103550/using-present-tenses-to-express-future-in-relative-clauses) Also [future or present with when](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56459/future-or-present-with-when) and [“While” and “When” phrases in the future tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/while-and-when-phrases-in-the-future-tense), among others. Short answer - in your context, only non-native speakers use ***will come***. Natives talk about ***When** something **happens***.

Comment: Where did you find the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the angel of death will come, none will be able to evade him.

Is perfectly correct, but very old fashioned. If  written today, I would suspect that the author was imitating the style and diction of a much older source, probably the King James Version of the Bible. I would not write this, and I would not advise writing it except with the intent of imitating a now obsolete style.

That said, there is no numerical limit on the number of clauses that use "will", if each one uses it properly.

Answer (score 0):

> <strike>When the angel of death will come, none will be able to evade him.</strike>

is not correct. Please see the links in @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica's comment.

> **If** *the angel of death comes*, none will be able to evade him. *(=a weaker form, the angel might or might not come)*

> **When** *the angel of death comes*, none will be able to evade him. *(=a stronger from, the angel will come)*

Note how *when* stresses the speaker's certainty. They are sure that the event will happen.

You can express it by using 2 sentences.

> The angel of death **will** come. *[When he does,]* None will be able to evade him.